# Propiedad MaxCursors de FireDAC con Oracle

Tags: oracle, delphi

Me encuentro trabajando en Delphi XE7 con los componentes de FireDAC y con conexión a una base de datos de Oracle, para evitar el error 01000 sobre el número excedido de cursores abiertos, modifique la propiedad TFDTopResourceOptions.MaxCursors de FireDAC, este problema ha sido solventado, pero no estoy segura de que número colocar a la propiedad, en Oracle tengo open_cursors=300, coloque este mismo número a MaxCursors y el error 01000 continúo apareciendo, coloque MaxCursors=1 y también obtuve este mismo error, mis preguntas son, ¿Cuál es el número que se debe de colocar con relación al valor que se tenga en Oracle de open_cursors? y ¿Modificar el valor de MaxCursors provoca algún error secundario?

Comment: ¿Cuántas tablas/queries tienes abiertos a la vez en tu aplicación?

Comment: Al rededor de 3000

Comment: En realidad no parece un diseño eficiente. Me es difícil pensar en un proceso que requiera tal número de tablas abiertas a la vez. Estás segura de necesitar tantas tablas abiertas? Es decir, ¿No hay mejor forma de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Realmente tienes 3000 tablas/querys abiertos a la vez?
Si esa afirmación es correcta, yo revisaría el diseño de tu programa, algo no está bien definitivamente.
Puede ser hasta cierto punto lógico crear un TDatamodule con unos cuantos querys y mantenerlos abiertos para ganar efciencia, pero si ese número ha llegado a 3000, a 1000, a 100 o te diría que a 50 es que el diseño es incorrecto.